# Not able to get value of html textboxes in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

Guys I have a  issue in my code that I want to get value of html input type textboxes in javascript and assign value to hidden field.After that I want to used hidden field value in code behind file in c#, But hidden field always contains empty string Even if inputtype text boxes contain value.
My Java script:

```
 <script type ="text/javascript" >
        function myFunction() {
            var str1 = document.getElementById("amt3").value;
            var str2 = document.getElementById("amt4").value;
            document.getElementById("hf1").value = str1;
            document.getElementById("hf2").value = str2;
        }
    </script>
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="form-row row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <label class="form-label span4" for="slider">
                Range slider</label>
            <div class="span8">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate >
                      <asp:HiddenField ID="hf1" runat="server" />
                      <asp:HiddenField ID="hf2" runat="server" />
                <div id="slider-range"    class="slider" >
                </div>
                <input type="text" id="amount1" style="border: 0; color: #ED7A53; font-weight: bold;
                    box-shadow: none;" />
                <input type="text" id="amt3" value="10" runat="server"     style="border: 0; color: #ED7A53; font-weight: bold;
                    box-shadow: none;" />
                <input type="text" id="amt4"  value="20" runat="server"    name="amt4" style="border: 0; color: #ED7A53;
                    font-weight: bold; box-shadow: none;" />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk" runat="server" onclick="lnk_Click" OnClientClick ="myFunction()">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ***Hidden fields*** and ***textboxes*** both are server side contrls, so should be accessing them with ClientIDs as

```
        var str1 = document.getElementById("<%= amt3.ClientID %>").value;
        var str2 = document.getElementById("<%= amt4.ClientID %>").value;

        document.getElementById("<%= hf1.ClientID %>").value = str1;
        document.getElementById("<%= hf2.ClientID %>").value = str2;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use ClientID in javascript, as the ids of server controls (which have attribute runat="server") are changed in generated html if ClientIDMode is not set to static.

```
var str1 = document.getElementById("<%= amt3.ClientID %>").value;
var str2 = document.getElementById("<%= amt4.ClientID %>").value;
document.getElementById("<%= hf1.ClientID %>").value = str1;
document.getElementById("<%= hf2.ClientID %>").value = str2;
```

Comment: You were just a bit faster then me :-)

Comment: Did you change all of them?

Comment: Yes I changed Both of them.

Comment: You have to change all four, same applies to hidden fields as well. You can see the result after being applied to hidden fields. Just put a alert to show the value str1.

Comment: Thanks @RobAngelier, I can guess it cant be you.

Comment: @Adil after applying this Now it is showing amt4 and amt3 doesnt exist here(in javascript).

Comment: There was typo of copy / paste, @user2164964 sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

A working example:

I modified it a bit to make it work without asp controls.

http://jsbin.com/aqayan/1/

Your issue is server side vs client side ids, you must make sure you have all ids correct in the browser. Open up Chrome web tools, and manually check the elements have the IDs you think they have in console.

Comment: Thx But I have to use hidden fields in code behind which isnot happening